# Why do we use int sqlite3_bind_int(sqlite3_stmt*, int, int) in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

What is the meaning of this in Objective C?

```
int sqlite3_bind_int(sqlite3_stmt*, int, int)
```

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html

Answer (score 2):

This code is function declaration in **C** - language. As **Objective-C** is fully compatible with **C**, any **C** code can be executed in **ObjC**